# Build failing since last update

Tags: android, android-studio, build, android-gradle-plugin, actionbarsherlock

I cannot build my Android project since I updated Android studio about ten days ago. I updated it again yesterday, but I still cannot build project. Worst thing is I cannot determine the source of this problem (I'm Android noob really).

In build report window, it says:

**Run build** > Run tasks > :app:processDebugResources > Execute TaskAction:

> org.gradle.tooling.BuildException: Failed to process resources, see
>   aapt output above for details.    at
>   com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask.invokeAaptForSplit(LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask.java:512)
>     at
>   com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask.doFullTaskAction(LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask.java:249)
>     at
>   com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.IncrementalTask.taskAction(IncrementalTask.java:106)
>     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor179.invoke(Unknown Source)    at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalTaskAction.java:46)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:121)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:110)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:92)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:62)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:60)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:97)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:87)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:52)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
>     at
>   org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:248)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
>     at
>   org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:241)
>     at
>   org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:230)
>     at
>   org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:123)
>     at
>   org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
>     at
>   org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:104)
>     at
>   org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
>     at
>   org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:626)
>     at
>   org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:581)
>     at
>   org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)    Suppressed:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Some file processing failed, see logs for
>   details       at
>   com.android.builder.internal.aapt.QueuedResourceProcessor.waitForAll(QueuedResourceProcessor.java:121)
>         at
>   com.android.builder.internal.aapt.QueuedResourceProcessor.end(QueuedResourceProcessor.java:141)
>         at
>   com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.QueueableAapt2.close(QueueableAapt2.java:104)
>         at
>   com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask.doFullTaskAction(LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask.java:293)
>         ... 47 more Caused by:
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute
>   aapt  at
>   com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.processResources(AndroidBuilder.java:809)
>     at
>   com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.processResources(AndroidBuilder.java:797)
>     at
>   com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask.invokeAaptForSplit(LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask.java:491)
>     ... 48 more Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error:
>   check logs for details    at
>   com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.getDoneValue(AbstractFuture.java:503)
>     at
>   com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:482)
>     at
>   com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$TrustedFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:79)
>     at
>   com.android.builder.internal.aapt.AbstractAapt.link(AbstractAapt.java:34)
>     at
>   com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.processResources(AndroidBuilder.java:807)
>     ... 50 more Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error:
>   check logs for details    at
>   com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.getDoneValue(AbstractFuture.java:503)
>     at
>   com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:462)
>     at
>   com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$TrustedFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:79)
>     at
>   com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.QueueableAapt2.lambda$makeValidatedPackage$1(QueueableAapt2.java:166)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     ... 1 more Caused by:
>   com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error:
>   check logs for details    at
>   com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess$NotifierProcessOutput.handleOutput(AaptProcess.java:443)
>     at
>   com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess$NotifierProcessOutput.err(AaptProcess.java:395)
>     at
>   com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess$ProcessOutputFacade.err(AaptProcess.java:312)
>     at
>   com.android.utils.GrabProcessOutput$1.run(GrabProcessOutput.java:104)

**Java compiler:** > failed linking references

**Android issues:** > ../../.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/actionbarsherlock-4.4.0.aar/278d29925e50f728f41382ea6efbdca1/res/values/values.xml > error: resource android:attr/popupPromptView is private.

This project uses actionbarsherlock ever since I started it 2 years ago and this is my project's fifth version increment, I never had such issues.

I've invalidated cache and cleaned project countless times. I deleted folders: .gradle, gradle, grdl, grdl.gradle, .idea, build, and deleted .iml file.

I tried with higher minSdkVersion and compileSdkVersion, nothing helped.

What else should I post here in order to reveal the cause of inability to build?

Comment: I'm facing the same problem. Did you manage to solve it?

Comment: In case anyone else is having the same problem I got around it by adding `android.enableAapt2=false` to my project's `gradle.properties` file. Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46241073/1329901

Answer (score 0):

Check following things and update:

1. `minSdkVersion 16` >= 14
2. `compileSdkVersion 27`
3. support lib version `27.1.1`
4. Find `android:attr/popupPromptView` in whole project and remove it as logs say it is now private.
5. Change actionbarsherlock to AppCompat and see if the error persists and update

Comment: Android studio says:Failed to find Build Tools revision 27.1.1 and after I click on the link to install it, popup window says: All packages are not available for download! The following packages are not available: - Package id build-tools;27.1.1

Comment: Regarding popupPromptView - it is not referenced anywhere in my project, it is a part of actionbarsherlock and problematic line is in ../../.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/actionbarsherlock-4.4.0.aar/278d29925e50f728f41382ea6efbdca1/res/values/values.xml

Comment: add `google()` to your repositories block in project level gradle file

Answer (score 0):

First take a backup of project folder. Then delete all build folder inside app and outside of app folder. Then delete other folders and files which are not needed excepts "app" folder, build.gradle,build.properties, settings.gradle files. Then open this project in android studio and add new gradle settings. After sync your project and configured gradle settings, click Build -> Rebuild project. If everything right I think successfully project will be build. Try this.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was missing a resource file, adding it as a response, so maybe someone that comes to the same question tries it, i.e. `file.xml` in the `res` folder.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved it as follows.

First you can solve it by adding `android.enableAapt2=false` to the project's `gradle.properties` file as some people mention, but this is soon to be deprecated option so not good in longer run.

The problem of course is that `actionbarsherlock` has not been supported anymore from 2014, and some things break.

I solved the problem by bringing the `actionbarsherlock` into the project and doing necessary modifications:

1. Copy the necessary files into your project, I have just downloaded the last release from http://actionbarsherlock.com/. Merge **both folders** from `ActionBarSherlock\actionbarsherlock\src` into your project, and also `ActionBarSherlock\actionbarsherlock\res`
2. Link to `android-support-v4.jar` library, any version of it seems to work
3. Replace `com.actionbarsherlock.R` with `com.yourname.R`
4. Remove `android:popupPromptView` in `app\src\main\res\values\abs__attrs.xml`, the original problem maker, is actually a not used resource.
5. Follow the steps described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35473639/using-actionbarsherlock-with-android-support-v4-version-23) to fix minor compilation problems caused by old code.

Hope that helps